# 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat - Friday the 4th at 0:00 UTC / Thursday the 3rd at 8pm EDT

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Friday the 4th at 0:00 UTC / *This is Thursday the 3rd at 8pm EDT.***

**[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=5&day=4&year=2012&hour=0&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3305/skeptics-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the final election phase.  This means that I am looking at the 3rd-5th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=skeptics.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

---

**The [full transcript of the town hall chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3305) is now available. Thanks to all of the participants. Those nominees that missed the chat can still enter the room and answer questions, so this transcript is subject to change!**

Comment: I am currently at a scientific conference, so my schedule is quite limited between conference activities, and air travel.  I filled out the availability as best as I could with these constraints.

Comment: Please make sure the time is Europe-friendly!

Comment: @Sklivvz, we all live all across the world, our community here is extremely global. We have mods and candidates in Europe, The Americans, and Australia. The time will probably be unfriendly to at least one person, but what can you do about that in a global community? Only schedule so the *most* people who are interested can attend.

Comment: @sam fair enough. However i think that midnight in the middle of the week is basically cutting out Europe. Not a schedule where most people can attend, sorry :-( I am certainly unlikely to show up, as many other Europeans who actually have a job/life...

Comment: I don't randomly choose the time.  I take the responses I get from the candidates and pray there is a time they can all make it.  If that isn't the case, then I pick when the most of them can attend.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff out of 6 candidates, 2 are from the US, 4 from Europe - you are asking 2/3rds of the candidates to come here in the middle of the night on a week day. Also, [prayer doesn't work](http://buckcash.com/opinions/iconspicsetc/MayoPrayerStudy.pdf) ;-)

Comment: @Sklivvz no, what I asked was "when can you do this - you tell me". I used the availability people gave me and did a best fit based on that.

Comment: Is Oddthinking not in the running?

Comment: @Chad no, he's [not](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/1730/96)... :-(

Comment: Sorry for my absence (I fell asleep). I’ll try giving answers to the starred questions during the day.

Comment: Is there a way to post the transcript as a static page on Meta?  I just find the chat format rather counter intuitive for a Q&A session like that.  I'll put my answers in as time allows in the chat though.

Comment: @Larian I'm sure that's possible - I'm happy to do it manually and put the responses under the appropriate questions and so on. I'll give it another day or so for those that missed the chat to provide their answers.

Comment: Whoops, this could have been fun. I spent the last few days transitioning from a user support trip in Bermuda to coming back to Halifax.